# How do I represent views of a list in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, oop

Suppose I've a main list of elements. Then I have lists of subsets of the elements that are in the main list (so it's like views of the main list). When items are removed from the "views" they're not removed from the main list. When items are removed from the main list, they're removed from the "views". Of course items have numerical ids.

This has to be done in a way that is easy to map in Hibernate and maybe it uses CASCADE on DELETE.

Comment: First try to think about how you want the data to be stored in the database, then map the database schema to Hibernate entities. What you call a view could very well be the result of a query.

Comment: I know how to do that. I I wanted a good oo representation

Comment: So, why don't you show us your database schema and ask us how to best map this schema, then?

Comment: Again, I don't want to map a database schema. I WANT A NICE OO PATTERN.